# Session Cookie wont get deleted/go away in Google Chrome > Devtools

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, google-chrome-devtools, session-cookies, devtools

[image]

I cannot delete/remove this cookie from chrome,

I tried:

1. Open `chrome://settings/`
2. Click `"Show advanced settings ..."`
3. Navigate down to System section and disable `"Continue running background apps when Google Chrome is closed"`. This will force Chrome to close completely and then it will delete session cookies.

still this indestructable cookie still there:

it still there after I closed the chrome tab > open a new one > visit the site

I tried deleting this cookie in `chrome devtools` multiple times and it still wont go away

any help will be appreciated